# Silverlight textblock not wrapping when there are trailing white spaces

Tags: silverlight, word-wrap, textblock

I recently found out that a silverlight textblock won't wrap lines if the Text property holds a string with many trailing white spaces; if you trim the string, the text is correctly formatted. Do you know if this is a known bug?

To reproduce the problem, try this:

```
<Grid Width="200" Height="100">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid Background="LightBlue">
    <TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
  </Grid>
  <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="LightYellow">
    <TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit                                     " TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

You should see a blue square with correct wrapping and a yellow square with a strange wrapping. Try adding TextTrimming, it's also quite interesting...

Comment: Can include a small but complete reproduction of this "bug" in the question?

Comment: I see the problem. I'll have a go on a machine that has SL5 RC installed see if perhaps its been fixed.  Its interesting that VS designer shows the same problem which would suggest that this would be a problem in WPF as well.